# Bash scripting, write special characters to file

Tags: bash, scripting, echo

I would like to write to file variable what have value like:

```
#include "..\..\cfg\plot.es"
```

I'm using:

```
echo "$var" >> "file.txt"
```

variable $var is readed from file:

```
while read var; do

    if [[ "$p" =~ "CONFIGURATION" ]]
    then
        echo 'sth' >> $te
    else
        echo $var >> $te
    fi
done < $out_file
```

but in result I get

```
#include "....cfgplot.es"
```

How to solve that without qouting every character?

Comment: You cannot save into a variable using `echo 'sth' >> $te`. This will only output to a file (is $te is set) or show an "ambiguous redirect" (if $te is not set). Use `te=$(echo "sth")` or directly `te="sth"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the `-r` option to `read`:

```
while read -r var; do ...
```

From the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read

> -r
>
> > If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.

And you **must** quote the variable when you use it:

```
echo "$var" >> "$te"
```